# OS X Ram Viewer

Tags: macos, memory

I am starting to become an intermediate C++ programmer and messing around with memory allocation and would like to take a look what is going on behind the scenes. For instance, I would like to see whats going on in the 0x7ff8ecaf7 region of *virtual memory* (correct me if I'm wrong) in the picture below. Is there a way to view the *virtual memory* contents of RAM in OS X?
[image: assembly dump]

Comment: The debugger will allow you to do that for your process

Comment: You may want to read and understand the concepts behind virtual memory management.  It is not as simple as 'reading' the contents of RAM. Each process has a dedicated address space which the OS dynamically maps to physical resources.

Comment: Here's Apple doc about virtual memory: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/AboutMemory.html

Comment: you might want to be more specific in your title.

Comment: @Hefewe1zen he mite be, like I am also, writing app that would benefit from having root access: a binary viewer for either the app itself when running as user, or in my case the entire RAM of the computer (running as root). My one will while (true) constantly display this onscreen by scaling the image down to your window size + as ASCII, Hex, Image, Sound, and so forth.